# Error with Dropdownlist Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

In `shownotice.aspx` page has a Repeater control to show the notice loaded from Database (sql server 2008) and a Dropdownlist control for filtering: `all notices`(default value = 0)`/lecturer's notices`(value=1)`/ student notices` (value=2).

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownlist_Changed"
            AutoPostBack="true" >
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0"> All notice </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1"> Lecturer </asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="2"> Student </asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

NOTICE table in database

```
 NOTICE(id, title, content,object)
```

object = `1` --> notice for lecturer

object= `2`--> notice for student.

Please take a look at my code below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        bool check = BindRepeater(madoituong, maloai);
        if (check == false)
            LabelError.Text = "There is no notice.";
    }
}

private bool BindRepeater()
{
    string sql = "";
    string key = DropDownList.SelectedValue;
    if (key == "0")
        sql = "select * from NOTICE";
    else
        sql = "select * from NOTICE where object=" + key;

    DataTable tb = EXECUTEQUERYSQL(sql);
    if (tb.Rows.Count > 0)
       {

        Repeater1.DataSource = tb;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
        return true;

         }
    else
        return false;
}

public void DropDownlist_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool check = BindRepeater();
    if (check == false)
        LabelError.Text = "There is no notice.";
}
```

All I want is:

- when client accesses `shownotice` page -> key= 0 --> Repeater loads all notices in NOTICE table (both for lecturer and for student)
- Then client chooses `Lecturer` or `Student` to filtering and display notices by object.

When I built this page, the program worked fine if it has some notices for lecturer (object=1) and some notices for student (object=2) in Database.

But when it only has notices for lecturer or only notices for student--> program worked wrong.

**For example:**

There is only one record in NOTICE table:

id= 1, title= aaa, content= holiday, object=1

When I choose Lecturer or Student --> it always show notice `aaa` , it should show messsage "There is no notice" when I choose `Student` option.

**Try to debug:**

When I choose `Student` option: `Datatable tb = null` and return `false`,  the program jump into `if` statement and hit line: LabelError = "There is no notice."; But after finish debugging, the Repeater still shows notice `aaa` instead of message.

Help!!! I really dont know why when I debug, the program hit the line LabelError = "There is no notice."; but then, there is no LabelError Message appear. Help!!!

Comment: Where is your Binding method

Comment: @SurajSingh I miss that statements when copy and paste, I've just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  DataTable tb = EXECUTEQUERYSQL(sql);
        Repeater1.DataSource = tb;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
        return true;

    if (tb.Rows.Count > 0)
       {
           return true;       
       }
    else
        return false;
```

See here you are binding your `Repeater` only if when `RowCount` >0 , So when your row count is 0 then your repeater is not getting updated and it's displaying 
 previous values , You have to bind your `Repeater` again to update it's value but when there are no values in table and your `RowCount` is zero your `if` condition do not let Repeater to bind again.

Comment: But it still workes fine when it has notices for student and lecture (some for student, some for lecturer), the repeater is getting update and display notice for each object
It only workes wrong when there is only one kind of notice (only notice for student or only for lecturer)

Comment: @VyClarks Yes cause at that time it is fulfilling `if (tb.Rows.Count > 0)` condition and that is causing your `Repeater` to bind again, fetching you updated values. Just remove that condition `if (tb.Rows.Count > 0)` it will work but let me check if there is any other sophisticated way then removing `if ` condition ,However your problem is that only

Comment: Oh dear, thanks you, I've understood your answer, I remove (tb.Rows.Count > 0) and it workes fine. But I want to show Message: There is no notice. How can I do that without if statement??? Hope you can give me a advice